# Apple devices incompatible Javascript code

Tags: javascript, ios, arrays, compatibility, array.prototype.map

I'm working on complex pages containing **Javascript** functions that must be executed on several targets including mobile devices, both Androids tablets and Apple iPads and iPhones.
Anyway everytime an Apple iOS device finds the following code stops without any apparent reason and without returning any errors. Before this code I have **jQuery** and **bootstrap** libraries. If I remove the function everything works fine. The function must return the element having its index closest to the given one:

```
function getClosestTS2(arr,tk) {
    // Returns the element kaving the ts closest to tk
    var closest= Object.keys(arr)
        .map(k => ({ k, delta: Math.abs(tk - k) }))
        .sort((a, b) => a.delta - b.delta)[0].k;
    return closest;
    }
```

If I run the code in any other environment different from iOS works without any problem. Any clue?

Edit: added debug screenshot from *browserstack.com* as suggested by **CBroe**
[image]

[image]

Comment: How exactly have you _checked_ for errors …?

Comment: @CBroe, the Javascript code is unable to preoceed after this piece of code. I cannot see the debug console as I don't have an iMac or any other Apple system. But I detected that if I remove this function the page is loaded and works correctly, if this piece of code is present the javascript execution is breaked and the document.ready is never initiated (the code above is outside document.ready). Hope it helps.

Comment: Then you could use a service like browserstack.com to test, it gives you access to the developer console.

Comment: Update, just tested on a iMac with Sierra 10.13.3 the function works, while on iPad with iOS 9.3.5 the jaavascript execution breaks up when this function if found. Very strange.

Comment: Probably different Safari versions, and the one that comes with 9.3.5 does not support some of the methods you are trying to use there ...?

Comment: May be but the code I've used is pretty standard as you can see.

Comment: That’s not going to get us anywhere, I’m afraid. See to it that you get error messages shown, anything else isn’t going to be productive here. (Again, browserstack.com gives you console access when testing, and I think that is available even in the free version.)

Comment: @CBroe, I installed browserstack.com Extension in my Chrome browser, configured the application and tried to debug. The message I receive from console is "SyntaxError: Unexpected token '>' at linje 1638 that is remapped to the point where is written .map(k => ({ k, delta: Math.abs(tk - k) })). I'm completely unable to understand what's wrong with this piece of code.

Comment: https://caniuse.com/#feat=arrow-functions ... not supported in iOS 9.3

Comment: @CBroe, you're right! Everything is clear now! I need to check the host iOS version before attemping to use this. I'll post a temporary solution below. Many thanks again.

Comment: There are "transpilers" available to convert your ES6/ECMAScript 2015 code into "older" JavaScript, that is in turn understood by "older" browsers as well - f.e. https://babeljs.io/ That allows you to keep writing your code "the modern way", without having to exclude older browsers, so maybe check out if that could be an option that works for you.

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out by CBroe the problem the arrow-functions is not supported in several versions (even quite recent) so I need to replace that function with the following (less efficient):

```
function getClosestTS2(arr,k) {
    var d;
    var mind=4294967296;
    var mink=0;
    for(e in arr){
        d=Math.abs(e-k);
        if(d<mind) {
            mink=e;
            mind=d;
            }
        }
    return mink;
    }
```

This will make no use of arrowing-functions and can be safely run on iOS < 9.3